# Python - Ошибка 404 при парсинге сайта в телеботе

Tags: python, telegram-bot, beautiful-soup

Пытаюсь в телеботе сделать парсинг сайта через API, но когда запрос был введён,бот выводит ошибку 404 .

Запрос передаётся через обработчик сообщений.

Если этот парсер будет сделан в консольном приложении или через TKinter он будет отлично работать, я так понимаю, что запрос неправильно передаётся в другую функцию, как бы это можно было бы исправить?

Вот код:

```
import requests
import telebot
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

token = "1886531469:AAGpg2lFas1O_MBLA0SKh15JRASbqmubZp4"

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите запрос")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, info)
def info(message):
    req = requests.get("https://plati.io/api/search.ashx?",
                params= {
                    "query" : message,
                    "visibleOnly" : "true",
                    "response": "json" 
                })

    ans = req.json()["items"]
    for i in ans:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, i["name"])
bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты передаёшь в параметрах запроса (params) по ключу query объект сообщения, а не его текст. Верный вариант выглядит так:

```
def info(message: telebot.types.Message):
    req = requests.get("https://plati.io/api/search.ashx",
                params= {
                    "query" : message.text,
                    "visibleOnly" : "true",
                    "response": "json" 
                })
```